# LNK1181 Error while compiling the core after adding a module

Tags: c++, azerothcore

I'm trying to compile my core with some modules but i'm getting the following error when building `worldserver`:

`cannot open input file '..\..\..\modules\RelWithDebInfo\modules.lib'    worldserver`

This error only happens when compiling with the `mod-gain-honor-guard` module. I've installed a repack before that came with this module pre-installed, which makes me think that i'm the one missing something.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

*I've compiled the core succesfully with only one module, then i've added the one mentioned before and that error came up. CMake didn't show me any error when i regenerated the source for building after adding the module*

Answer (score 2):

You always need to regenerate the source in CMake when you add or remove any files to the source.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention that i've already done that. CMake didn't show any error after adding the module, so i generated and tried to build and then that error came up

Answer (score 2):

Did you get the module via `git clone`? If not, and it's a direct download, you need to remove the `-master` or any other branch name from the folder name.

Comment: I've tried both ways, cloning and downloading the module and removing the `-master`. Both ways failed with the same error

Comment: The source of the module might be outdated and not match the core anymore. Hard to tell what's actually up without a full error log. Feel free to upload one to a gist and post it here.